# How to import utils from keras_unet

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to add utils from keras_unet in google colab, but I have a problem.

```
import tensorflow as tfs
from keras_unet import utils
```

*keras-unet init: TF version is >= 2.0.0 - using `tf.keras` instead of `Keras`*

> ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install keras-unet before importing as follows

```
!pip install keras-unet
from keras_unet import utils
```

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!